# Initial smell is no longer recognized

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for the phenomenon where a person's brain stops
recognizing the initial smell of something?

For example – the initial smell of one's own "constitutional duty." That smell will be recognized by that person for only a moment or two.

The word is very specific to "smells."
It is a word I learned, but forgot, in a hazardous materials training class.
It is more of a scientific type word than a generic type word such as "adjust."

Answer (score 3):

*[Olfactory fatigue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_fatigue):*

> **Olfactory fatigue**, also known as **odor fatigue** or **olfactory adaptation**, is the temporary, normal inability to distinguish a particular odor after a prolonged exposure to that airborne compound.[1] For example, when entering a restaurant initially the odor of food is often perceived as being very strong, but after time the awareness of the odor normally fades to the point where the smell is not perceptible or is much weaker.

Comment: Thanks Reg. I do not believe that's the word though. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Another term for this is _olfactory habituation_.

Answer (score 0):

See if [limen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limen) fits.

> Limen -n. the smallest/lowest detectable sensation.

Comment: All contributions thus far have been perfectly sensible. None of these words, however, have been foreign to me for decades. I thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[Olfactory/Odor] **desensitization**, adaptation (already mentioned by RegDwigHt), and **cross-adaptation** are considered as perils in the [wine-tasting world](http://www.wineanorak.com/wineblog/wine-science/desensitization-adaptation-and-cross-adaptation-perils-for-wine-tasting).

Comment: Maybe I will find the time to reconnect with my Hazardous Materials Prof. in-order to get to the bottom of this. If I do, I will keep you all informed. Thx